# How many ways to park $n$ cars?

Tags: combinatorics

There are $n$ parking spaces along a one way road down which $n$ drivers are travelling.Each driver goes to his favorite parking space and parks there if it is free; otherwise, he parks at the nearest free place down the road. If there is no free space after his favorite, he drives away. How many lists $a_1, … , a_n$ of 
favorite parking spaces are there which permit all of the drivers to park?

Comment: Have you tried by hand for small $n$?

Comment: I wonder why the author of the problem chose to use a one way road? It seems the intention is for the parking spaces to be linearly ordered, but that would seem to happen more naturally if the drivers were driving the same direction down a two way road. One way roads often have street parking on both sides.

Comment: Previous question, with links to solutions in comments: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1406949/showing-that-only-n1n-1-of-all-the-possible-nn-choices-assure-a-full?rq=1