# probability event linked with uniform order statistics

Tags: combinatorics, definite-integrals, uniform-distribution, order-statistics

Given$$U_1,\ldots,U_N\stackrel{\text{iid}}{\sim}\mathcal U(0,N)\quad N\in\mathbb N^*$$
consider the [event](https://fivethirtyeight.com/features/can-you-make-room-for-goats/)
$$\bigcap_{i=1}^N\{U_{(i)}\le i\}$$
where
$$U_{(1)}<U_{(2)}<\cdots<U_{(N)}$$
denote the order statistics. This event has, I believe, the probability
$$\frac{N!}{N^N}\,\int_0^1\int_{u_1}^2\cdots\int_{u_{N-1}}^N\,\text du_N\cdots\text du_1$$
Is there any chance this integral has a simple expression for all $N$'s? Computation is easy for $N=2,3,4$ but I do not see a pattern.

Comment: The $U_i$ are iid, thus the sets $\{U_i\leq i\}$ are independent from each other. The probability $p$ of the intersection of these sets is thus simply given by the product of the probabilities of the individual sets, i.e. $p=N!/N^N$. I do not understand how you came up with this complicated integral.

Comment: @Andreas, Note that the question concerns the order statistics $U_{(i)}$ and not the original variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The  probability is
$$
(N+1)^{N-1} \over N^N
$$
This process is equivalent to the parking function problem. In that problem, there are $N$ cars trying to park in a parking lot with $N$ spaces. The spaces are numbered $1$ to $N$. Each car independently chooses a preferred space number uniformly between $1$ and $N$. The cars then try to park one at a time. If a car prefers space number $a$, then they will successfully park if an only if one of the spaces in the range $\{1,\dots,a\}$ is available. The parking function problem asks, in this setup, what is the probability that all cars will successfully park?

In order for all cars to succeed, there needs to be at most one car which prefers space $1$, at most $2$ cars which prefer spaces $1$ or $2$, and in general, for each $i\in\{1,\dots,N\}$, there needs to be at most $i$ cars which prefer spaces in $\{1,\dots,i\}$. This is exactly equivalent to the condition $\{U_{(i)}\le i\}$ for your problem.

For a combinatorial proof that exactly $(N+1)^{N-1}$ of the $N^N$ preferences vectors are successful, see [my other MSE answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1406949/), which quotes a solution by Richard Stanley.

Comment: Well-spotted and great reverse engineering. I actually moved from a parking-like puzzle to the continuous formulation hoping from an easier resolution!