# Proving a combinatorial quantity is uniformly distributed

Tags: probability, combinatorics, uniform-distribution

**Shorter Version.** Pick a list $\mathbf{a}$ of length $n$, taking in values in $\{1,2,\ldots,n+1\}$ at random. Then sort $\mathbf{a}$ in increasing order to obtain $\mathbf{a}' = (a_{(1)}, \ldots, a_{(n)})$, and count the number of times $a_{(k)} \leq k$ holds.

> **Conjecture:** The resulting count takes in values $0, 1, \ldots, n$ equally likely.

How do we prove or disprove this conjecture?

---

**Longer Version.** The setting is as follows:

- $\mathcal{A}_n = \{1, 2, \ldots, n+1\}^n$ is the collection of all lists of length $n$ taking integer values between $1$ and $n+1$.
- For each list $\mathbf{a} \in \mathcal{A}_n $, we sort $a$ in increasing order to obtain $\mathtt{sort}(\mathbf{a}) = (a_{(k)})_{k=1}^{n}$. Equivalently, $a_{(k)}$ denotes the $k$th smallest element in $\mathbf{a}$. For example,
  $$ \mathtt{sort}(5, 1, 2, 7, 5, 2) = (1, 2, 2, 5, 5, 7). $$
- Then, define the function $\mathtt{below}(\mathbf{a})$ as the number of $k$'s for which $a_{(k)} \leq k$ holds, that is, $\mathtt{below}(\mathbf{a}) = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \mathbf{1}[a_{(k)} \leq k]$. For example,
  $$ \mathtt{below}(5, 1, 2, 7, 5, 2) = \mathtt{below}(\underline{1}, \underline{2}, \underline{2}, 5, \underline{5}, 7) = 4. $$

While playing with this setting with computer software, I noticed some patterns that eventually led me to formulate the following conjecture:

> **Conjecture.** Sample $A$ from $\mathcal{A}_n$ uniformly at random. Then $\mathtt{below}(A)$ is uniformly distributed over the set $\{0, 1, \ldots, n\}$.

How do we prove or disprove this?

---

**Discussion.** For example, if $n = 2$, then

$$ \begin{array}{c}
\mathbf{a} \\ 
(1, 1) \\ (1, 2) \\ (1, 3) \\ (2, 1) \\ (2, 2) \\ (2, 3) \\ (3, 1) \\ (3, 2) \\ (3, 3)
\end{array}
\quad
\longrightarrow
\quad
\begin{array}{c}
\mathtt{sort}(\mathbf{a}) \\ 
(1, 1) \\ (1, 2) \\ (1, 3) \\ (1, 2) \\ (2, 2) \\ (2, 3) \\ (1, 3) \\ (2, 3) \\ (3, 3)
\end{array}
\quad
\longrightarrow
\quad
\begin{array}{c}
\mathtt{below}(\mathbf{a}) \\ 
2\vphantom{,)} \\ 2\vphantom{,)} \\ 1\vphantom{,)} \\ 2\vphantom{,)} \\ 1\vphantom{,)} \\ 0\vphantom{,)} \\ 1\vphantom{,)} \\ 0\vphantom{,)}\\ 0\vphantom{,)}
\end{array}
$$

and hence $\mathtt{below}(A)$ takes values $0, 1, 2$ with equal probabilities. Also, using computer software, I tested this conjecture for $n \leq 7$. However, brute-force search goes quickly out of hand as $n$ gets larger. And I was unable to come up with a nice explanation of this observation, letting alone a proof.

---

**Context.** This can be thought of as a discrete analog of the fact that, for the Brownian bridge $(B_t)_{t\in[0,1]}$ joining $(0, 0)$ to $(1, 0)$, the occupation time $\int_{0}^{1} \mathbf{1}[B_t \geq 0] \, \mathrm{d}t$ is uniformly distributed over $[0, 1]$. Indeed, a version of invariance principle tells that

$$t \mapsto n^{-1/2}(\lfloor nt\rfloor - a_{(\lfloor nt\rfloor)})$$

tends to the Brownian bridge as $n \to \infty$ in an appropriate sense. So, it is reasonable to expect that $\mathtt{below}(A)$ is approximately uniformly distributed. What is quite surprising is that $\mathtt{below}(A)$ seems *exactly* uniformly distributed.

Comment: This is true up to $n=9$.

Comment: Just a thought, without any idea yet how make use of it: The number of lists with each value of $\mathtt{below}(\mathbf{a})$ is $(n+1)^{n-1}$, the number of labelled trees with $n+1$ nodes, and the Prüfer sequences for these trees are lists of $n-1$ numbers up to $n+1$.

Comment: Proving that there are $(n+1)^{n-1}$ lists $\bf a$ for which $\mathtt{below}({\bf a})=n$ is exactly the [parking function problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1406949/177399), so your question is an extension of that famous problem. Interesting!

Comment: @joriki, Thank you for expanding the validity of the conjecture!

Comment: @MikeEarnest, That's a nice observation! It seems suggesting the right keyword to begin with, which is great to know. Also, given the plethora of bijective proofs involved, we might possibly tackle this problem by devising some bijections among the sets $\{\mathbf{a}:\mathtt{below}(\mathbf{a})=k\}$, $k=0,1,\ldots,n$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We begin with sorted lists. There are $\binom{n+1+n-1}n=\binom {2n}n$ such lists by identifying each sorted lists to the number of solutions to $x_1+\cdots + x_{n+1}=n$ in nonnegative integers. Here, $x_i$ is the number of $i$'s in a given list.

Then we identify a given sorted list $\bf a$ to a lattice path $L(\bf a)$ in $[0,n]\times[0,n]$, (paths consisting of $\rightarrow$, $\uparrow$)
by putting $x_i$ $\uparrow$'s on the $i$-th vertical line from the left. Then for a given sorted list $\bf a$,

below($\bf a$) is the number of $\uparrow$'s of $L(\bf a)$ in the region $y\geq x$ (this is called the "exceedance" in the third proof here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number).

Following the procedure there:

$\bullet$ Starting from the bottom left, follow the path until it first travels above the diagonal.

$\bullet$ Continue to follow the path until it touches the diagonal again. Denote by X the first such edge that is reached.

$\bullet$ Swap the portion of the path occurring before X with the portion occurring after X.

It is proved that exceedance within $\binom {2n}n$ lattice paths is uniformly distributed on $\{0,\ldots, n\}$. Thus, each number is attained exactly $C_n = \frac1{n+1}\binom {2n}n$ times. Indeed, the procedure gives a bijection between all paths with exceedance $k+1$ and all paths with exceedance $k$. Moreover, this exceedance dropping bijection does not change the multiset $\{x_1,\ldots, x_{n+1}\}$.

Therefore, in the following
$$
{\bf a} \mapsto {\rm sort}({\bf a}) \mapsto L({\rm sort}({\bf a}))\mapsto {\rm exceedance}(L({\rm sort}({\bf a}))),
$$
each number in $\{0,\ldots, n\}$ is attained equally many times.

Comment: This is beautiful! Thank you :)

Comment: Thank you for clear explanation of your nice problem, also the bounty.